# JQuery datepicker cannot perform date formatting

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am stuck in a simple problem. I am using JQuery datepicker plugin. Where I am getting probem though is in formatting its date. It is currently showing me current date in the form of: **mm/dd/yy**. I want it in: **yy/mm/dd**.

What I have tried:

```
$("#" + contactDateTextBox).datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    selectDefaultDate: true,
    dateformat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: new Date(),
    showSpeed: 'fast',
    showAnim: 'fadeIn'
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Also:

```
$(".selector").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});

$("#" + contactDateTextBox).datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    selectDefaultDate: true,
    dateformat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: new Date(),
    showSpeed: 'fast',
    showAnim: 'fadeIn'
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Also tried is:

```
$("#" + contactDateTextBox).datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    selectDefaultDate: true,
    dateformat: $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", new Date()),
    minDate: new Date(),
    showSpeed: 'fast',
    showAnim: 'fadeIn'
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

But I am not able to get the correct format. Please help.

Comment: Make sure you've initialized jQuery core + jQuery UI. This should work: `$(".selector").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });` I tried it out myself: [**Click**](http://jsfiddle.net/ypjZX/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your options, `dateformat` should be `dateFormat` (with a capital "F"). This should do the trick:

```
$("#" + contactDateTextBox).datepicker({
    ...
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    ...
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the only silly mistake I was doing. Working for long hours always land you in this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another plugins for formatting Date Strings. Like the following:

[jquery-dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)